# Difference between Kenorland and Arctica

Tags: paleogeography

Whats the difference between Kenorland and Arctica? Is it believed that both existed or is it a matter of choosing one or the other?

Both consist of Laurentia, Baltica, and Ur.
But Kenorland includes Kalaharia while Arctica includes the Siberian Craton.